# Добавление в список с помощью функции

Tags: python, python-3.x, список

Есть код. По логике должен работать, но нет. При добавлении элемента в цикле с помощью метода `append()` он переписывает все элементы, а надо сохранить результаты каждой итерации. Пробовал и `insert()`, и саму функцию в цикл ставил, не помогает. Пример кода:

```
def time(lists, var):
    lists[0] = lists[0]+var
    return lists
time_all  = []
lst = [0,1,2,3,4]
for i in range(5):
    time_all.append(time(lst, i))
    lst = time_all[i]
print(time_all)
```

выдает это:

`[[10, 1, 2, 3, 4], [10, 1, 2, 3, 4], [10, 1, 2, 3, 4], [10, 1, 2, 3, 4], [10, 1, 2, 3, 4]]`

а надо :

`[[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 1, 2, 3, 4], [3, 1, 2, 3, 4], [6, 1, 2, 3, 4], [10, 1, 2, 3, 4]]`

P.S. Надо именно списками. Надо менять в цикле один элемент, но потом он проходит ряд проверок и могут меняться другие элементы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас `time_all` состоит не из пяти разных списков, а из пяти копий одного и того же списка! Другими словами - `time_all` состоит из пяти ссылок на один и тот же элемент. 
Можете проверить добавив в конце `print (time_all[0] is time_all[2])`. Результат будет True.
Или изменить любой элемент в любом из списков, он изменится во всех пяти:

```
time_all[2][3] = 40
print time_all
```

> Output: [[10, 1, 2, 40, 4], [10, 1, 2, 40, 4], [10, 1, 2, 40, 4], [10, 1, 2, 40, 4], [10, 1, 2, 40, 4]]

**Как исправить**: нужно не присоединять уже имеющийся список (в этом случае список не присоединяется, а просто создается ссылка), а создать новый и присоединять уже его.

Один из вариантов:

```
for i in range(5):
    new_list = list(time(lst, i))
    time_all.append(new_list)
print(time_all)
```

Вместо

```
new_list = list(time(lst, i))
```

можно использовать

```
new_list = time(lst, i)[:]
```

Comment: Вместо цикла в одну строку: `time_all = [list(time(lst, i)) for i in range(5)]`

Comment: плохо, когда функция изменяет аргумент и возвращает его. Можно было бы поменять `time()` функцию (переименовать и возвращать новый список) К примеру: `add_to_head = lambda lst, value: [lst[0] + value] + lst[1:]` не трогая входной список