# Почему изменение одной ячейки в матрице (списке списков) изменяет значения во всем столбце?

Tags: python, массивы, циклы

```
tab1 = [[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 9, 9, 9],
        [3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
        [5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1],
        [4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3],
        [6, 6, 6, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5],
        [8, 8, 8, 6, 6, 6, 4, 4, 4],
        [7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 6, 6, 6],
        [9, 9, 9, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8],
        [2, 2, 2, 9, 9, 9, 7, 7, 7]]

tab1z = [[0]*9]*9

for i in range(0,9):

    for j in range(0,9):

        if tab1[i][j] == 1:

            tab1z[0][j] = [i,j]
print(tab1z)
```

Выводит:

```
[[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [2, 6], [2, 7], [2, 8]],
 [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [2, 6], [2, 7], [2, 8]],
 [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [2, 6], [2, 7], [2, 8]],
 [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [2, 6], [2, 7], [2, 8]],
 [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [2, 6], [2, 7], [2, 8]], 
 [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [2, 6], [2, 7], [2, 8]], 
 [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [2, 6], [2, 7], [2, 8]],
 [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [2, 6], [2, 7], [2, 8]],
 [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [2, 6], [2, 7], [2, 8]]]
```

Хотя, по-идее должно быть так:

```
 [[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [2, 6], [2, 7], [2, 8]],
```

А дальше нули.

Comment: Пожалуйста, прочитайте про генераторы. И вам жить станет легче.

Comment: Мой вопрос заключается в другом: почему добавило в массив 9 раз, а не 1?

Comment: Смежный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/805239/282277

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема в том как вы создали:

```
tab1z = [[0]*9]*9
```

вы реплицируете один и тот же объект (внутренний список) 9 раз. В итоге получите 9 ссылок на один и тот же список в памяти:

```
In [16]: list(map(id, tab1z))
Out[16]:
[277357384,
 277357384,
 277357384,
 277357384,
 277357384,
 277357384,
 277357384,
 277357384,
 277357384]
```

измение любого элемента вызовет следующий эффект:

```
In [20]: tab1z[0][2] = [1,1]

In [21]: tab1z
Out[21]:
[[0, 0, [1, 1], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, [1, 1], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, [1, 1], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, [1, 1], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, [1, 1], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, [1, 1], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, [1, 1], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, [1, 1], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, [1, 1], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

т.к. вы изменяете элемент одного и того же списка в памяти (в моем случае `id` этого списка: `277357384`)

Comment: Спасибо! Исправил, все работает!